# How do I create JSON objects programmatically in playframework 2.1 scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework-2.1

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaJson

That document says the idiomatic style of json creation is:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
Json.obj( "key" -> "value )
```

However this fails to compile as String -> String is not String -> Json.JsValueWrapper

It appears that play provides the code needed for implicit conversions in play.api.libs.json.{DefaultReads, DefaultWrites}

How do I get these implicit conversions into scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misspelt your import statement; it should be `import play.api.libs.json.Json` (it's important to remember Scala is case-sensitive). Fixing that, the code works:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import play.api.libs.json.Json
Json.obj("key" -> "value")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import play.api.libs.json.Json
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"key":"value"}

scala>
```

Comment: That was a transcription error, not an error in the code I was running, however after trying again I'm unable to re-create the problem I've had.

Comment: It is however, a problem I've come across multiple times, so I'd really like to work out what I'm doing wrong